# Logic: Show that {∧, ↔, +} is complete, but every proper subset of it, isn't. (Symbol "+" is exclusive or)

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I know that, for example, to show {¬,→} is not complete, if φ is a propositional type that only includes ¬,→ has truth value T, then every propositional variable in φ must have a truth value T. But ¬p has not this property (if p has a truth value T then ¬p has a t.v. F).

But when the case is {∧, ↔, +}, I really don't know how to prove this.

Comment: We call them "proper subsets", not "genuine subsets".

Comment: You should start at the definition of *all* your operations  {∧, ↔, +} (not just "$+$ is exclusive or").

Answer (score 0):

You probably already have an example of a minimal complete set of operations, like $S=\{\wedge,\neg\}$.  So proving that a set of operations is complete is as easy as showing that you can derive all of the operations in $S$.

After that, all you need to do is show that none of the three doubleton subsets of $\{\wedge,\leftrightarrow,+\}$ are complete.  You could do that like the example you cited where you describe a feature that all of the derivable operations have and then show that there is a logical operation that doesn't have that feature.  The usual suspects for counterexamples are $\bot$, $\neg$, and $\to$ because a set of operators either can't return false if all the arguments are true, can't be contrary, or can't be asymmetric".

Comment: Are you sure {∧,↔,+} *is* complete?

Comment: @ProfessorVector I went back and forth on it, but I'm 90% sure.  Unless I'm mistaken, $\neg p$ is $p \leftrightarrow (p+p)$, so that makes the completion obvious.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure that you checked it, since your answer doesn't mention it.

Comment: @ProfessorVector I'm not doing his homework for him.